# Django complex models and Nested Queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

How to write a complex query to
1) create a student,Course,OptionOne -  example -

```
student_name=John,
  rollno = 20
  course1 = this field will refence a field in OptionOne, OptionOne will 
  reference the course desired. enter code here

  **illustration** - John Selects mathematics as the first option, while Mike 
  selects Geoography as Option One, Mathematics as Option Two
```

2) Select all students who opt mathematics as option one
   3) Select the student alongwith the course he opted

```
django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
 class Course(models.Model):
 course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 course_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PriorityOne(models.Model):
    course = models.OneToOneField(Course, verbose_name=("Course"), 
             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PriorityTwo(models.Model):
     course = models.OneToOneField(Course, verbose_name=("Course"), 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PriorityThree(models.Model):
     course = models.OneToOneField(Course, verbose_name=("Course"), 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Student(models.Model):
    student_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rollno = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course1 = models.OneToOneField(PriorityOne,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course2 = models.OneToOneField(PriorityTwo,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course3 = models.ForeignKey(PriorityThree, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yeah I am not sure if you qre asking an architecture question in regards to your model development or if you don't know how to write certain syntax for what you want to accomplish. An official question would be great please.

Comment: yeah its a model development, i tried many to many and it didnt workout

Comment: My question is: how to create a models to structure these complex relationship

Comment: a student has an option to select three courses among a list of courses, but he has to give a priority among these 3 selected courses

Answer (score 0):

You can use a M:M field here if multiple students can take the same course. The course will have the ManyToMany field referencing the `Student` model. This means multiple course objects can be associated with a student and a Student can have multiple Courses. I know it seems a little weird on where you define the M2M field. If you want to set a priority list, then you can define an integer field with the top priority course pk. That is of course one way of doing it. Any of the syntax for M2M fields are here [Django M2M docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). If you need further explanation, I will be glad to help.

Comment: First of all thank you for the  response, i am to implement many to many field. But i  dont know how to implement the priority. the main problem is student can set and can have their own priority list. therfore, priority list can be vary from one student to another

Comment: Hmmm you can have a middle model `Priority` inbetween them which will take 1 course and priority number. Then your Student will have multiple priorities which will be a foriegn key field. This probably isn't an ideal implementation.